# Groovy-based Spring Boot DI by example

Tags: groovy, dependency-injection, spring-boot

In a traditional Spring DI-based application, you define an `application.xml` file and wire your beans as needed. Then in your main class you can just grab the `ApplicationContext` (that is configured with those wirings) or you can even make a class `ApplicationContextAware`.

But it seems everything has changed with Spring Boot. With Boot, it seems as though you annotate classes with `@Component`, however I have been unable to find any really good concrete examples of its use. Furthermore, I don't see solutions to scenarios where there are different instances of the same class/component that you want to wire into dependent beans differently, or how `@Component`-based injections work with Groovyisms like `@Canonical`. So I figured I would start with a concrete example and see if anyone could point me in the right direction:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
@Canonical
class Fizz {
    boolean checked
    String umberGUID
}

@Canonical
class Buzz {
    Fizz fizz // # always use Fizz instance #1 for all Buzz instances
    int value
}

@Canonical
class Widget {
    Fizz fizz // always use Fizz instance #2 for all Widget instances
    String magicNumber  // we need to define and wire a different magic number into each Widget instance
}

===
The example below is how I would accomplish dependency injection in Guice
using the classes and constraints above:
===
@Canonical
class Fizz {
    @Inject @Named('checked')
    boolean checked

    @Inject @Named('umberGUID')
    String umberGUID
}

@Canonical
class Buzz {
    @Inject @Named('buzz_fizz')
    Fizz fizz

    @Inject @Named('buzz_value')
    int value
}

@Canonical
class Widget {
    @Inject @Named('widget_fizz')
    Fizz fizz

    @Inject @Named('magic_number')
    String magicNumber
}

class MyGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    void configure() {
    }

    // I wont write Provider methods for everything above, just showing
    // 2 here as as an example.
    @Provides @Named('buzz_fizz')
    Fizz provideBuzzFizz() {
        new Fizz(true, 'A', null)
    }

    @Provides @Named('widget_fizz')
    Fizz provideWidgetFizz() {
        new Fizz(false, 'D', 'blue')
    }        
}
```

**How would I wire these beans up with each other in Spring Boot?** The end result should be my ability to access, say, a `Widget` instance inside some fourth class, say, "`HerpDerp`", and have the `Widget` instance have properly-injected `fizz`/`magicNumber` fields on it. If that answer requires more info, I'm happy to whip something up, just ask!

Comment: The Spring and Spring boot projects have some of the best documentation around. I would suggest you start by reading the DI sections there. Also, they point out numerous example projects in contained in their GitHub repositories.

Comment: Thanks for the closevote @cjstehno (+1) but please note: this question is about Spring DI **+ Groovy**, specifically the use of `@Canonical`. I showed research by already explaining what I have extracted from the docs based on reading them. This question is **not** a dupe, and is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so please refrain from closevoting! The docs *might* contains *hints* as to how to solve my particular problem at hand, but nothing concrete.

Comment: So @smeeb, I am unclear of a couple of points in your question. 1) What is the relevance of `@Canonical` in your question? `@Canonical` is nothing more than a composite annotation that combines several other Groovy annotations, the @EqualsAndHashCode, @ToString and @TupleConstructor annotations. All of which are only to create a default implementation of the equals and hashCode, toString methods and default Constructors. Non of which impact and are relevant to Spring/Spring Boot.

Comment: 2) For each `Fizz`-you state `Buzz` should always use `Fizz` #1, and `Widget`-`Fizz` #2. The default for Spring beans is to construct as a singleton (one instance per VM). How would you declare (or qualify) `Fizz` instances in Spring to instantiate the 2 unique `Fizz` beans? 3) For `magicNumber`-You state to 'wire' it, implying it is a bean. You don't typically see this in Spring. Normally you wouldn't inject a String that changes each time, constants would be more common. You could use a factory method, and a better approach is to set the value in a constructor, creating a unique magicNumber.

Comment: Thanks @pczeus (+1 for both). Please see my update, it might help give you some context. I changed my code to include a snippet of what the wiring/DI might look like if I was using Google Guice (which I'm very familiar with). 1) So with Guice, I can use javax `@Inject` annotation on each field, which tells Guice that it needs to inject them from bindings defined in the `MyGuiceModule` module. **I'm wondering if Spring Boot/DI offers the same capabilities as `@Inject` so that I can continue using `@Canonical` without having to define a constructor.**

Comment: 2) Please see my update, this is how a solution would look like in Guice-land, **I'm wondering what it looks like with Spring Boot.** Meaning, in Guice-land, you can write `@Provides` methods that will provide instances of a particular class for use by the injector. Furthermore, if you have multiple instances of the same class that you wish to inject differently, you can use `@Named(...)` annotation to perform wirings as you need them. **Does Spring offer a similar mechanism?**

Comment: 3) I understand that you normally don't wire strings, but that doesn't mean you *can't* or that you *shouldn't*. For instance, a connection string or set of credentials defined in an external config file might need to be injected into 1+ service clients. But yes, I agree, it's probably a bad example, so I'd say let's just focus on injecting two different instances of `Fizz` into the other beans for the sake of helping me understand this! Thanks again and I look forward to any answers you can share!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description of your problem, This is really not a question dependent on features of SpringBoot, or Groovy, but is more of a question about Spring and how the configuration is different between the XML based configuration: `application.xml`, vs. a Java based configuration and/or with the use of annotations like `@Component`.

I bring this up, because if you are looking for documentation, then you would really want to refer directly to the Spring documentation on the Java based configuration to get the most information. A good start would be [5.12.1 Basic concepts: @Bean and @Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).

As I mentioned in the comments to your question, I don't think the `@Canonical` annotation affects this at all. `@Canonical` is simply a composite annotation, used to auto-generate commonly used methods to your Groovy classes. Specifically, as stated directly in the [`@Canonical` GroovyDoc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html) :

> The @Canonical meta-annotation combines the @EqualsAndHashCode, @ToString and @TupleConstructor annotations. It is used to assist in the creation of mutable classes. It instructs the compiler to execute AST transformations which add positional constructors, equals, hashCode and a pretty print toString to your class.

None of which affects how beans are 'wired' up in your application, regardless of whether you are using Java, Spring, Groovy, or Spring Boot.

**With all of that said, how would you accomplish your requirements using Spring Boot and Groovy?**

I think the best way to demonstrate would be with a concrete example. 
To provide a good example, I have created a Test SpringBoot project, with Gradle as the build tool and Groovy as the language of choice. For this example, I have place the Groovy classes in the `com.app.bootinjection` package. Here is a screenshot showing the folder and package structure:

[image]

To build the application, I have created the `build.gradle` file, seen in the image, with the following contents:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.30')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.1')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.7.1')
}

springBoot{
    mainClass = 'com.app.Application'
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

Note in the `build.gradle` file, I have added 2 compile time dependencies on Jackson libraries. The 'core' library to support JSON output, and the 'dataformat' library to make the JSON output formatted nicely when viewing in a client like the browser.

Because this is to be a SpringBoot application, I have created a simple `Application` class annotated with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, which contains the main method and starts up our application:

**Application.groovy:**

```
package com.app

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)
    }
}
```

I also created a Groovy class representative of each class mentioned in your question: `Fizz`, `Buzz`, `Widget` and `HerpDerp`. Each is annotated with both the `@Canonical` annotation and the `@Component` annotation. When component scanning is done, Spring will see the `@Component` annotation and as a default will construct a single (singleton like) instance of that class and register it as a bean. By default, the bean name will be the same name of the class, with the first letter in the class name lower cased. So, the `Fizz` class will be instantiated as a bean and registered under the bean name 'fizz'. For more information, see the Spring docs in [Section 5.10.1 @Component](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html). By the way, you could change the 'scope' of the bean to have a new one created every time it is injected, using the `@Scope(value = "prototype")`. But, I would recommend only doing that if absolutely required.

**Fizz.groovy:**

```
package com.app.bootinjection

import groovy.transform.Canonical
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Canonical
@Component
class Fizz {
    boolean checked
    String umberGUID = 0
}
```

Note: I have defaulted `umberGUID` to a value of 0 for demonstration/output purposes only.

**Buzz.groovy:**

```
package com.app.bootinjection

import groovy.transform.Canonical
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

import javax.annotation.Resource

@Canonical
@Component
class Buzz {
    @Resource
    Fizz fizz1
    int value
}
```

**Widget.groovy:**

```
package com.app.bootinjection

import groovy.transform.Canonical
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

import javax.annotation.Resource

@Component
@Canonical
class Widget {
    @Resource
    Fizz fizz2

    @Resource
    Buzz buzz

    @Resource
    String magicalNumber
}
```

**HerpDerp.groovy:**

```
package com.app.bootinjection

import groovy.transform.Canonical
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

import javax.annotation.Resource

@Component
@Canonical
class HerpDerp {
    @Resource
    Widget widget

    @Resource
    Fizz fizz
}
```

Note the usage of `@Resource` to inject beans into our objects. On our projects, we switched from `@Autowired` initially to `@Inject` and now to the `@Resource` annotation. In most cases, we have found the `@Resource` to be more appropriate and work more often within our projects. For example, notice the declaration of `Fizz fizz1` in the class `Buzz`. Using the `@Resource`, it will inject the proper instance of `Fizz` where the bean name matches `fizz1`. For more clarification on when/why to use either, refer to Section 5.9.3 of the Spring docs, which states:

> Tip
>
> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not primarily use @Autowired, even if is technically capable of referring to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, use the JSR-250 @Resource annotation, which is semantically defined to identify a specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type being irrelevant for the matching process.
>
> As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through @Autowired, because type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific collection or map bean by unique name.
>
> @Autowired applies to fields, constructors, and multi-argument methods, allowing for narrowing through qualifier annotations at the parameter level. By contrast, @Resource is supported only for fields and bean property setter methods with a single argument. As a consequence, stick with qualifiers if your injection target is a constructor or a multi-argument method.

**Sow how do we declare multiple beans of the same instance with different names?** Remember you can use the `@Component` annotation alone to have Spring create a single instance of the class, defaulting the bean name to the class name (first character lower cased). You can also specify the name to override the default when using the `@Component`. For example: `@Component("myBean")`. Still, a single instance will be created. You can also specify the 'scope' as mentioned before using the `@Scope("prototype")` annotation. Now, each time the bean is injected, a new instance is created and injected.

If you want to control the number of beans created, specify unique names, and inject with the unique names, you need a more configurable solution. The preferred solution compared to the XML configuration is a Java based solution. You can create any class and configure it with the `@Configuration` annotation to indicate to Spring this class is intended to provide configuration information. For this example, I have created the `ApplicationConfiguration` class:

**ApplicationConfiguration.groovy:**

```
package com.app

import com.app.bootinjection.Fizz
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Fizz fizz1(){
        new Fizz(checked: true, umberGUID: 1)
    }

    @Bean
    Fizz fizz2(){
        new Fizz(checked: false, umberGUID: 2)
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype") 
    String magicNumber(){
        System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```

In the configuration, we create 2 methods for the `Fizz` class to create 2 unique fizz instances: fizz1 and fizz2. The name of the method will become the bean name, hence the method `fizz1()` and `fizz2)`. Also note that only one instance of each is created. Spring takes care of instantiating the beans and only creating a single instance of each.

Now if you look back at the `Buzz` class, you will see that we use the `@Resource` annotation to inject the instance of the `Fizz` class that matches the bean name `fizz1`, which matches the bean name declared in the configuration class. The same is true for `fizz2` in `Widget`. Also for demonstration purposes, notice that we also inject a `Fizz` instance in the `HerpDerp` class, called simply `fizz`. Since we annotated the `Fizz` class with `@Component`, when Spring performs the component scan, it will see the annotated class and by default create a separate instance with the default name of `fizz`.

In the configuration class, we have another bean method, annotated with `@Bean` called `magicNumber()`. Because we want the magic number injected to be unique every time, I have annotated that bean with a scope of prototype: `Scope("prototype")`. The bean, of type `String`, is then injected in the `Widget` class as required.

Finally, to put it all together, I have created a REST web service controller that simply injects the `HerpDerp` bean instance and returns it, which is then serialized to JSON to demonstrate the output we expect. The results are seen by accessing http://localhost:8080 :

**TestController.groovy:**

```
package com.app.bootinjection

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

import javax.annotation.Resource

@RestController
class TestController {
    @Resource
    HerpDerp herpDerp

    @RequestMapping("/")
    def index(){
       [herpDerp]
    }
}
```

With a resulting output of:

```
<HerpDerp xmlns="">
    <widget>
        <fizz2>
            <checked>false</checked>
            <umberGUID>2</umberGUID>
        </fizz2>
        <buzz>
            <fizz1>
                <checked>true</checked>
                <umberGUID>1</umberGUID>
            </fizz1>
            <value>0</value>
        </buzz>
        <magicalNumber>1464240486303</magicalNumber>
    </widget>
    <fizz>
        <checked>false</checked>
        <umberGUID>0</umberGUID>
    </fizz>
</HerpDerp>
```

I hope this proves to be a comprehensive demonstration that covers the topics you are trying to accomplish. I think you will see that Spring/SpringBoot make it very easy to produce the results you are looking for. Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, awesome, awesome answer @pczeus (+1) - I wish I could upvote this more!!! Two quick (hopefully) questions: **(1)** What happens if I use `@Resource` annotations on properties that live inside classes that are **not** annotated with `@Component`? Error? Or does Spring just ignore those injections? And **(2)** Do I really have to annotate *every* class with `@Component` or is there a way to say "*Hey, Spring, use DI to wire up all my classes, or all the class under the XYZ package?*" Thanks again!

Comment: To answer question 1) -- Annotating a class with `@Resource` that is not a bean registered with Spring will simply be ignored and the property will not get injected. Of course, that could cause a null pointer or other issue if you 'thought' it was going to be injected and available. No explicit error is generated, so be cautious of that.

Comment: Regarding 2) I don't see a mechanism that Spring provides to create beans for every class or specify a package. This is intentional and makes sense. Every bean created is a singleton stored in memory. So Spring does this intentionally so beans are not unnecessarily created and done explicitly.  Spring does provide an API allowing you to manually register a bean, so this could be done in a custom fashion. But, I think the details of how to do it and if it's possible are broad to put here and should be a separate question. Your's is a special case, and I can see where you might like to do it.

Comment: You should either create a separate question asking how to register a bean for all classes in a specific package, or I can do it for you if you like and see if it's possible to come up with a good solution.

Comment: I've created a separate question that may prove useful to find the best solution to register all classes within a package as Spring beans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548350/is-it-possible-to-register-all-classes-within-a-package-as-spring-beans

Comment: @pczeus great answer! Would you mind taking a look at my question please?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374032/configure-spring-boot-app-using-only-groovy-beans-grails-style-dsl
It is similar to this one but with grails DSL style for more conciseness.