# Is it possible to register all classes within a package as Spring beans

Tags: java, spring, groovy, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I'm familiar with Springs Java based configuration options, including the usage of `@Component` and `@Configuration` in conjunction with `@Bean` annotations to register Spring beans.

However, when converting a decent size project to Spring, it can be very labor intensive to systematically touch all classes in the project and update with `@Configuration` `@Bean`s or annotating each class with `@Component`. We have a large Groovy project to be converted and I would like to simplify the process.

**My question:** Is there a facility provided in Spring that allows you to tell Spring to auto-configure all valid bean candidate classes within a specific package?

If not, what other options are available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner` is all you need.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
        ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner scanner = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(context, false);
        scanner.addIncludeFilter((metadataReader, metadataReaderFactory) -> true);
        scanner.scan("net.company.name");
        context.refresh();

        A a = context.getBean(A.class);
        System.out.println(a.toString());
    }
}
```

You can pass custom logic in include filter if you want. In current version every class in the provided package will be included as a bean.

But it is impossible to build a right dependency structure on your classes automagically, it really depends on the scope you want. You need to do it by your hands.

Comment: Can this be used with an existing ApplicationContext that is injected? Is it possible to get a handle to the Scanner from an existing ApplicationContext and add the package at runtime to be included in scanning and/or is it acceptable to have more than one Scanner for the same ApplicationContext?

Answer (score 7):

I'd do pretty much the same thing that Roman did, only I'd do it at build time, not at runtime, using code generation. The rationale here is that I strongly prefer magic to happen at build time to magic that happens at deploy time.

In the simplest version, write a main method that scans the package (instead of reflections api, I'm using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s ClassPath scanner) and creates a `@Bean` method for every class it finds.

For the Code generation, I'd use [JCodeModel](https://github.com/phax/jcodemodel):

```
public class PackageBeanGenerator {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String packageName = args[0];
    JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();
    // create class definition
    JDefinedClass springConfig = codeModel._package(packageName)._class("SpringConfig");
    springConfig.annotate(Configuration.class);

    for (ClassPath.ClassInfo classInfo : ClassPath.from(
                    PackageBeanGenerator.class.getClassLoader()
        ).getTopLevelClasses(packageName)) {

      Class<?> type = classInfo.load();
      String beanName = CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(
                           CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL,
                           type.getSimpleName());
      JMethod beanMethod = springConfig.method(JMod.PUBLIC, type, beanName);
      beanMethod.annotate(Bean.class);
      beanMethod.body()._return(JExpr._new(codeModel._ref(type)));
    }
    // write class to file
    codeModel.build(new File("/path/to/output/folder"));

  }
}
```

Comment: Both approaches (run time and build time) are good answers. I was hoping Spring would provide a way to handle all this for me, but it's becoming clear that's not available. Given that, I agree that a build time solution or utility is a better option. I hadn't thought of that and after your post, I'm leaning more towards creating a utility that would do similar to what you proposed, but instead manipulating the classes themselves, identify candidate beans and alter the source files themselves, which could then be put into source control. After all, this is really a conversion exercise.

Comment: @pczeus I'd be very careful with that approach. At the least, I'd save the changed sources to a different directory

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use your own [BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html)

```
@Component
public class CustomBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package.prefix", new SubTypesScanner(false));
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    for (Class clazz : allClasses) {
      GenericBeanDefinition gbd = new GenericBeanDefinition();
      gbd.setBeanClass(clazz);
      gbd.setAttribute("attributeName", "attributeValue");
      registry.registerBeanDefinition(clazz.getSimpleName() + "_Bean", gbd);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    // Custom post process the existing bean definitions
  }

}
```

See sample project at https://github.com/sandarkin/so-q37548350

Comment: Thanks Roman. I'm somewhat familiar with the ability to register a bean at runtime manuall using `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and the `postProcessBeanFactory` method. Your solution is very similar to those examples. I wasn't familiar with the `Reflections` API. Does that come from: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections ? Are you aware if the Reflections take into account classes that have not been loaded in a classloader yet? Meaning does it scan the .class files as well?

Comment: @pczeus, yes, I used reflection from ronmamo. Also I created the sample github project https://github.com/sandarkin/so-q37548350 which illustrates described approach.

Comment: About `Reflections`. Yes, it scans the .class files directly, what is proved by the [org.reflections.Reflections#scan()](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/blob/master/src/main/java/org/reflections/Reflections.java#L179) and [org.reflections.Reflections#scan(java.net.URL)](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/blob/master/src/main/java/org/reflections/Reflections.java#L241) methods.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding primitive, why not just do a simple find and replace in your IDE (e.g. search for "public class" in a package and replace with "@Component public class") ? That should be much quicker than trying to do anything programatically.